# How to display Chinese characters with Three.js

Tags: localization, three.js

I am using the OBJLoader to load a large 3D model (described in a .obj file) and I want to display the models name on its surfaces. Though it seems that Three.js can only display English characters. My question is how can I display Chinese characters in Three.js?

Comment: Never used Three.js myself but from looking at the TextPath.js source: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/core/TextPath.js, it seems that you can pass some parameters to it. If no parameters are set it will use the `helvetiker` font, which might not be able to show Chinese characters. Try another font which supports these.

Answer (score 2):

there are a couple of ways to display text (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Text-in-Three.js), but since exporting a chinese font might be more difficult, it might be easier to draw the chinese characters to a canvas texture and use the texture as a material in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Three.js doesn't display Chinese regularly because it doesn't support the charset. You have to load it dynamically.
It seems there're two methods to load: 1, `new THREE.TTFLoader().load('*.ttf')` , it loads a ttf file that support Chinese charset. But I failed.
2, `new THREE.FontLoader().load('*.json')` it loads a json file transformed by
the ttf on http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/ website.

But firstly you have to find a complete ttf file. I tried `方正兰亭超细黑简体` and `方正赵佶瘦金书` which both work, you can google and download ttf file. I found some ttf can't be identified by three.js completely. You perhaps see some Chinese char display normally but others still display '?'.

The final code snippets as following:

```
      const three_font = new THREE.FontLoader();
      three_font.load('*.json', function (font_font) {
        font=font_font
      })

// finally add text with font
const geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(
        {
          font: font,
          size, height: h, curveSegments: 4, bevelThickness: 2, bevelSize: 2, bevelEnabled: true
        });
      geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
      geometry.computeVertexNormals();

      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, pool.textMaterial);
      mesh.position.set(x * deviation, y, z * deviation);
      mesh.rotation.set(rx, ry, rz);
      scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you can use [Facetype.js](http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/) to get a Chinese font library, for example"YaHei_Regular.typeface.json" , then you can show Chinese characters.

```
var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    fontLoader.load("YaHei_Regular.typeface.json", (font)=> {
        this.font = font;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [msdf-bmfont-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msdf-bmfont-xml). This example uses [Microsoft YaHei](https://www.wfonts.com/font/microsoft-yahei).

charset.txt —

```
你好，世界
```

You may need to [install dependencies](https://github.com/Jam3/msdf-bmfont#install) first. Then:

```
npm install msdf-bmfont-xml -g
msdf-bmfont -f json yahei.ttf -i charset.txt --pot --square
```

and finally, use [three-bmfont-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-bmfont-text) to render the text.